# INSERT INTO string has to many characters, how can I bypass it? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I would like to create a list of insert into strings from a table I have and use that to import the rows into another table on another server in anothr database. The method works fine for small tables. Now I have a table where I select to many columns with to much characters. My output ends with (...)" and does not fill all my columns. Is there a way of bypassing it?

```
select    
    'INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('|| val1 ||', '|| val2 ||', '|| val3 ||','|| val4 ||', '|| val15 ||');' 
AS sqlstring 
from     
    table
where   
    col1 > 1018
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using pgAdmin3 to run your query and copy from result grid, right?

Go to "File -> Options -> Query tool -> Max. characters per column " and set it to 1000000000.

[image]